# Spring boot 2.1.x how to secure Actuator end points with basic auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to build a spring boot application and wanted to leverage the Actuator features, but I want to secure the end points of Actuator /health,/shutdown etc. I have the below configurations which does not seem to work. I.e., application never prompts for credentials or when hit from post man does not give 403. I tried various ways, even the one from spring documentation. Can any one please help with this. Again this is spring boot 2.1.x. I know there is a configuration that can be made in application.yml in the previous version of spring

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(ShutdownEndpoint.class, InfoEndpoint.class, HealthEndpoint.class,
                        MetricsEndpoint.class))
                .hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN").requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
                .authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
      roles:
      - ENDPOINT_ADMIN

management:   
  endpoints:  
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
    health:
      show-details: when-authorized
      roles:
      - ENDPOINT_ADMIN
    mappings:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 2):

This code can serve you as a reference to achieve BasicAuth for Actuator Endpoints Spring Boot 2.X. This is not the exact code. While Extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter you have to configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder to assign roles and passwords for the roles. Here I am using "noop" password encoder you can use a different one to provide more security.

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                            
                auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ROLE_USER").password("{noop}" + "USER_PWD").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("ROLE_ADMIN").password("{noop}" + "ADMIN").roles("ADMIN", "USER");
    }
```

Once AuthenticationManagerBuilder is configured now configure HttpSecurity by disabling csrf. Below code requires authentication for metrics alone using any role. You can customize according to the end points you need to authenticate. Make sure you exclude base url of Rest Controller from this Authentication. You can insert  `authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/baseurl").permitAll().and()`  in the below configuration code to achieve that. Below is an example to configure HttpSecurity.

```
protected void configure(Httpsecurity http) {
    http.csrf().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(MetricsEndpoint.class))
    .hasANyRole("ADMIN","USER").and().authorizeRequests().and().httpBasic();
}
```