# Spring Boot secure actuator endpoint with basic auth while securing other endpoints with Oath

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot service which is configured using Oath security like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
  }
}
```

The `actuator` endpoint was excluded from authentification, but now I need to secure it, but not with Oath as the other endpoints, but with Basic Auth with user/password. How can I achieve this? I'm using Spring-Boot version `2.0.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716532/spring-boot-2-1-x-how-to-secure-actuator-end-points-with-basic-auth

Comment: In the nutshell it's doesn't matter how to define Principle by Oath or Basic Auth. Please check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caCJAJC41Rk&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTYTEooakHchTGglSvkZAjnE&index=6